# How is the below multilevel inheritance working in .Net5?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, .net-5

1. In Image section 1, the intermediate class ***ClassA*** inherits the ***ClassASuper*** but does not override the ***Display*** method rather it gets overridden in sub child **ClassB** and it seems it working as expected.
2. In Image section 2, the intermediate class ***ClassA*** inherits the ***ClassASuper*** and does override ***Display*** method which further gets overridden in sub child **ClassB** also and it seems it is also working as expected.
3. In Image section 3, the intermediate class **ClassA** inherits the **ClassASuper** and does hide the ***Display*** method, which further gets overridden in sub child **ClassB** and it seems it is contradicting. --> ***Can someone explain how this is working behind the scene?***

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Section3, the new `Display` method hides the one inherited from the base class. It is the starting point for a new inheritance hierarchy. In this respect it is not any different from a totally new method with another name. You could have written e.g.:

```cs
public virtual void NewDisplay()
{
   ...
}
```

and override this one in `ClassA` and `ClassB`.

Therefore, a variable of type `ClassASuper` does not see this new method, because it is not overriding or implementing the original method. Since `ClassASuper.Display` is not overridden, it does correctly display

> Print from ClassASuper

If you want to use the new method, you must cast to `ClassA` (or `ClassB`):

```cs
((ClassA)classASuperA).Display();
((ClassA)classASuperB).Display();
```